# ODBC Driver Manager Data source name not found in php

Tags: php, odbc

I hired PHP developer to do small task, He deployed, show me demo and then its not working at all and developer is also not responding now.

**Task:**
Upload `.mdb` file save specific data into `phpmyadmin` database.

**Enviorment:** Local Virtual Machine `windows 2010 Server`

**Application:** Senrifugo HRM (open source)

**Error:** `SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

In Organization, People punch their attendance through machine and machine can export `.mdb` file with all data. Looking for only `Person Name`,`Check-in` & `Check-out`data and save into `phpmyadmin` database.

**Code**

```
<?php
require_once 'public/constants.php';
require_once 'public/site_constants.php';
require_once 'public/email_constants.php';
require_once 'public/emptabconfigure.php';
require_once 'public/db_constants.php';
require_once 'public/application_constants.php';
require_once 'public/mail_settings_constants.php';
require_once 'application/modules/default/library/sapp/Global.php';
require_once 'public/text_constants.php';


// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));



/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';


// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap();


$attendancesabsensemodel = new Default_Model_Attendancesabsense();

$dbName = MDB_DATABASE_PATH . "att2000.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("HERE 1");
}

try {
    $dbName = MDB_DATABASE_PATH . "att2000.mdb";
    if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
        die("HERE 2");
    }
    $database_path = realpath($dbName);
    $database = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$database_path; Uid=; Pwd=;");
  //  $date = new Datetime();
    $aujourdhui = gmdate("Y-m-d");
    $auj= gmdate("Y-m-d");
    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/

    $sql = "SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE, USERINFO.Badgenumber,USERINFO.Name
FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID
WHERE (((CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME)>=#$aujourdhui#))";
    //  $sql = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE  DATE('Y-m-d H:i:s','Checkintime') = DATE(NOW())";
  // die( $sql);
    /*** fetch into an PDOStatement object ***/
    $stmt = $database->query($sql);
    // print_r($stmt);
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if($auth->hasIdentity()){
        $loginUserId = $auth->getStorage()->read()->id;
    }

    //this will fetch row by row and allows to change column name, format, etc:
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       // die($row['USERID']);
        $json['USERID'] = $row['USERID'];
       // print_r($row);
        if($row['CHECKTYPE']=="I")
        {
            $json['CHECKTIME '] = $row['CHECKTIME'];
            $datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $auj.' 09:00:00');
            // A Hack using pages.dateformat.default: 'm-d-Y'`
            $datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['CHECKTIME']);
           // print_r($auj);
            $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
            $elapsed = $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
            $json['CheckinTimeLate '] = $elapsed;

            $data = array(
                'attendancesabsense'  => $row['Name'],
                'badgenumb'  => $row['Badgenumber'],
                'attendancecheckin'  => $row['CHECKTIME'],
                'attendancecheckout'  =>    "",
                'absensestatut'  => $elapsed,
                'createdby'  => $loginUserId,
                'modifiedby'  => $loginUserId,
            );


            $data['createddate'] = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['modifieddate'] = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['isactive'] = 1;
            $where = '';

            $Id = $attendancesabsensemodel->SaveorUpdateAttendanceAbsenseData($data, $where);
        }
        else{
            $json['CHECKTIME '] = $row['CHECKTIME'];
            $datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $auj.' 17:00:00');
            // A Hack using pages.dateformat.default: 'm-d-Y'`
            $datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['CHECKTIME']);


            $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
            $elapsed = $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
            $json['CheckOutTimeLate '] = $elapsed;

            $data = array(
                'attendancesabsense'  => $row['Name'],
                'badgenumb'  => $row['Badgenumber'],
                'attendancecheckin'  => "",
                'attendancecheckout'  =>    $row['CHECKTIME'],
                'absensestatut'  => $elapsed,
                'createdby'  => $loginUserId,
                'modifiedby'  => $loginUserId,
            );


            $data['createddate'] = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['modifieddate'] = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['isactive'] = 1;
            $where = '';

            $Id = $attendancesabsensemodel->SaveorUpdateAttendanceAbsenseData($data, $where);
        }



        $response[] = array('items' => $json);
      //  print_r($response);
    }



    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $database = null;

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo "INSERTION CRON JOB DONE !";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Application showing data from database.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application designed to help system administrators manage a MySQL or MariaDB database, so whatever you're doing isn't using a phpMyAdmin database. Perhaps you meant to say MySQL or MariaDB, this is a common misunderstanding. However, nowhere in your code do I see a connection to one of those databases, either (I admit that I just quickly looked through and may have missed it). As a side note, the code has several debugging statements left in that I would say indicate either a work-in-progress or that the developer wasn't very thorough...which is confirmed by his disappearance.

Comment: I'm guessing a bit here, but it seems that perhaps the error message indicates that the program wasn't able to read the att2000.mdb file. First your developer verifies the file exists (with `!file_exists($dbName)`, but then changes the path before opening it (`$database_path = realpath($dbName);`). Looking at the code, this seems like it could be the problem to me. I'd try adding some debugging lines to print the the paths represented by each variable and compare those, perhaps also add a check for whether `$database_path` exists. Again, I'm just guessing here based on the context and error.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch, connection file are included at the top. Actually Even I dont have any idea how this code is working, I have basic knowledge to do. but the thing is Developer is not traceable now. and I am stuck over here. any solution to replace or change can solve this issue?

Comment: There are several `require_once()` statements, but based on the file names it doesn't seem like any of them are actually performing the database connection. (though without seeing the contents of the files we can't really know for certain). I think your best bet is to withhold payment from the original developer, investigate whether you have grounds to pursue a legal case against him, and hire another developer to fix this. It's a lot to try to troubleshoot across the internet and if it's for a business then you should find a competent developer with whom you can have a long-term relationship.